# Scaling # of docker containers in AWS elastic beanstalk per EC2 instance [app architecture]

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, architecture, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a dockerized data application which runs long calculations and doesn't have much flexibility with multi-threading or async, thus multiple users is a growing problem. The docker image currently runs on Elastic Beanstalk (mainly just to familiarize myself with AWS) but I quickly noticed that horizontally scaling the EC2 instances, running at 1 docker container per EC2 instance, will be extremely costly. The app's calculations aren't extremely CPU-intensive, so it seems wise to instead take advantage of the number of containers per instance.

**Does Elastic Beanstalk have a strategy for deploying 'x' # of docker containers per EC2 instance and directing traffic accordingly? Or should I be focusing on a different AWS product entirely?** I'd like to have 10-20 copies of the same docker image available at a given time to handle traffic but not achieve this by directly increasing the # of EC2 instances to 10-20 with the load balancer settings.

As an aside, I know you can run multi-container apps by specifying such in your dockerrun.aws.json file, but my understanding is that you would do this primarily for deploying a single app that requires multiple ***different*** dockerized services. Are there instead config settings I can add to my dockerrun file to achieve what I'm looking for? ...without hard-coding 20 different copies of the image+port-mapping

Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
"Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "s3_bucket_name",
    "Key": "config_file"
},
"Image": {
    "Name": "image_name"
},
"Ports": [{
    "ContainerPort": 3838,
    "HostPort": 3838
}]
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different horses for different courses, you can use Elastic Beanstalk for the normal workload but you can not expect that much scalability and flexibility that [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) provides in case of Docker.

> Amazon Elastic Container Service (Amazon ECS) is a fully managed
> container orchestration service. Customers such as Duolingo, Samsung,
> GE, and Cookpad use ECS to run their most sensitive and mission
> critical applications because of its security, reliability, and
> scalability.

For you query

> I'd like to have 10-20 copies of the same docker image available at a
> given time to handle traffic but not achieve this by directly
> increasing the # of EC2 instances to 10-20 with the load balancer
> settings.

This is extremely easy with ECS, all you need to tell the replica number of your task and ECS will manage that **accordingly in one instance or across all instance in the cluster**.

> without hard-coding 20 different copies of the image+port-mapping

You do not need to create 20 copies, just **one copy of task definition with [dynamic port](https://medium.com/faun/understanding-dynamic-port-mapping-in-amazon-ecs-with-application-load-balancer-bf705ee0ca8e#:%7E:text=Well%20%2C%20Dynamic%20port%20mapping%20allows,on%20an%20Amazon%20ECS%20cluster.)** and place load balancer on top the service, ECS will manage the port so you do not need to worry about hardcoded and port conflict.
[image]

Plus you can also go [fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) which serverless container services and you will only manage application **"Zero server to manage"**

[image]

[new-launch-introducing-aws-fargate](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/new-launch-introducing-aws-fargate-con214-reinvent-2017)